# Underline with angled edges in CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I do underline with angled edges in CSS like the image below?

[image]

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: you can try something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mq5Lqate/)

Comment: I have tried before but I forgot to put the code and ideas of how to do. Sorry!!!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823361/text-underline-with-a-short-slant-line-at-the-end-using-css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/060Lgxk8/ ?

```
h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px 3px 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
h1:after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: -13px;
  bottom: 1px;
  transform: rotate(-35deg);
}
```

Try reading this code, so you'll understand how it works. It's pretty simple, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. It was very helpful. I was trying do, but I am always confuse about how to use after and before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `:pseudo` element with `border` and `skewx` to it

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  margin: 15px;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}
ul li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent black black transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I like this more because it doesn't require any complex positioning and can be responsive.