# Text underline with a short slant line at the end using CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to give my menu items a good loking underline effect when You hover over them. There should be a standard solid line with the same width as the underlined text, but at the end of that straight line there should be a short slant ending line smoothly connected to the previous straight part.

The desired effect should be like this:
[image: final underline look]

How can I do that?

HTML:

```
<ul class="my-menu">
<li class="my-menu-items">Home</li>
<li class="my-menu-items">About us</li>
<li class="my-menu-items">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Its pretty easy.. did you try it?

Comment: There are some parts of CSS that remained undiscovered for me, you cannot search for something if you dont know how its is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an absolutely positioned pseudo element using `transform: rotate()`

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 25%;
  transform: translateX(100%) rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Home</a>
```

Comment: Nice. I'd go with 45deg.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements.

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li:after, li:before {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
li:after {
  left: calc(100% - 3px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 15px;
  bottom: -5px;
}
li:hover:after,
li:hover:before {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="my-menu">
  <li class="my-menu-items">Home</li>
  <li class="my-menu-items">About us</li>
  <li class="my-menu-items">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Using pseudo-elements for both lines you can create animation changing width.

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
li:after, li:before {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  width: 0px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
li:after {
  left: 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}
li:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
li:hover:after {
  width: 15px;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<ul class="my-menu">
  <li class="my-menu-items">Home</li>
  <li class="my-menu-items">About us</li>
  <li class="my-menu-items">Contact</li>
</ul>
```